# How can I solve this Sudoku without guessing?

Tags: sudoku

I am fairly new to Sudoku and have hit a brick wall with this one. My colleague said it can only be solved with a guess and seeing how far you go. However, I agree with many on this site and you should not need to guess…it is a mathematical problem so no need to guess. I believe I have gone as far as I can, but welcome someone telling how to get one more number without guessing. Thanks.

[image]

(The blue cells were pre-completed.)

Comment: You forgot to clear the pencil mark 2s in the top right box.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's call the columns numerically from left to right 1...9, and the rows alphabetically from top to bottom A...I. We'll refer to a cell using its row letter, followed by the column number.

We are going to use

> the [XY Wing](https://www.learn-sudoku.com/xy-wing.html) technique

Let's consider the cells

> B1, C2, D1

They conform to that pattern, with

> - B1 being the middle cell
>  - C2 and D1 being the wings

We are sure that

> either C2 or D1 must be a 9

which means

> D2 can't be a 9

Now considering the cells

> D2 and F3, they must contain 1 and 2. 
>  They are a [Naked Pair](https://www.learn-sudoku.com/naked-pairs.html)
>  ⇒ D1 must be a 9

And then you'll be able to remove some candidates from

> the G row.

You can take it from here or use [this](https://www.sudoku-solutions.com/) website to get hints or solve the puzzle either partially or completely.

Comment: Thanks ielyamani . I will give this a go. I find the XWing technique a bit confusing, but your explanation is great. Thanks again.